# How to limit values for month, day and year in Angular UI Mask?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to mask in date input field with angular ui-mask. Here is the code sample.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ui-mask="99/99/9999" ng-model="date" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

Now I want to prevent the users from enter invalid month or day. eg. 15/35/2015. Please help..!!

Comment: ui-mask wasn't make for date input, therefore there is no built-in validation for date limitation. You should either write your own date validation or using a datepicker with a built-in date validation

Comment: **Refer describe Following Plunker link:
your problem is solved.** ***http://embed.plnkr.co/gE1WXaXsYI7zpWPkmvVS/preview***